# Razor Web Pages - Accessing the WebPage instance

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor

In ASP.NET web forms, I would access the page class by doing the following:

```
(Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler
```

Since the page was the HTTP handler for ASPX requests, this worked great.  This isn't an option for a razor web page (NOT talking MVC here, but the razor web pages web site), which I cannot access the `System.Web.WebPages.WebPage` class or can figure out a way to do so.  Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `WebPageContext.Current.Page` ?

Comment: Yes, I might be... let me check that out.